# Checking for a file and whether it is readable and writable

Tags: bash, permissions

I'm trying to write a script that will look for a certain .txt file saved to my desktop.  I want the script to be able to check if this file exists and then check to see if it is readable and writable.

Any hints?

Answer (score 44):

You needn't check if it exists, the checks for read and write permissions are enough:

From `help test`, a selection of relevant tests:

```
-a FILE        True if file exists.
-e FILE        True if file exists.
-f FILE        True if file exists and is a regular file.
-r FILE        True if file is readable by you.
-s FILE        True if file exists and is not empty.
-w FILE        True if the file is writable by you.
```

So you can try:

```bsh
FILE="/path/to/some/file"

if [[ -r $FILE && -w $FILE ]]; then
  # do stuff
else
  # file is either not readable or writable or both
fi
```

Comment: should it not be `if [[ -r $FILE ]] && [[ -w $FILE ]]` instead of `if [[ -r $FILE && -w $FILE ]]`?

Comment: @Videonauth see https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Conditional-Constructs, `&&` etc are allowed in `[[`

Answer (score 3):

```
test -r file.txt -a -w file.txt
echo $?
```

The return code is 0 if it is both readable and writeable.

Answer (score 1):

On some network protocols, file permssion might be reported wrong, and `-r` fails.

Use `head -c1` or `dd bs=1 count=1` to check readability.

```bash
is_readable(){
    head -c1 "$1" > /dev/null 2>&1
    return $?
}

if is_readable "$file"; then
    echo "$file is readable"
else
    echo "$file is not readable"
fi
```