# Command to check whether the current user has write permission

Tags: command-line, bash

I have to create a script to check if the current user has write permission on a file. If not, an error should appear.

I wrote this:

```
if [namei -m /path/to/textfile.txt | grep w]; then 
  echo "message"
```

But I seem to get a syntax error.

Comment: Did you forget `fi`?

Comment: IIRC the test command `[` needs a space after it: `[ namei …`

Comment: `[ -w "/path/to/textfile.txt" ] || echo "/path/to/textfile.txt is not writable by $USER."`  or change to && `[ -w "/path/to/textfile.txt" ] && echo "/path/to/textfile.txt is writable by $USER."`

Comment: What is the syntax error? Please post it, in full. [Edit] it into your question.

Answer (score 6):

Let's work through the issues with your code. As dessert mentioned in [a comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/980658/command-to-check-whether-the-current-user-has-write-permission/980773#comment1576018_980658), the first problem is the syntax of the `[` command. We need to put spaces between `[` and its arguments, because the shell uses spaces to separate fields, and thinks that `[namei` is the command you want to run.

I'm going to use a file in my home directory called `file`, which I know I have write permission on, in my examples. I have put your code on one line, to make it easier to test interactively. It will work in the same way as if there were a newline after `then`.

```
$ if [namei -m playground | grep w]; then echo "writeable"
No command '[namei' found, did you mean:
 Command 'namei' from package 'util-linux' (main)
[namei: command not found
```

Let's fix the spaces around `[` and `]`:

```
$ if [ namei -m playground | grep w ]; then echo "writeable"
>
```

Now I get a prompt to type something, a `>`. The prompt tells me that the shell is waiting for me to enter something. The simplest form of the syntax of `if` is

```
if condition; then command; fi
```

so the shell is waiting for the `fi`. If I enter it at the prompt, I get this:

```
$ if [ namei -m file | grep w ]; then echo "writeable"
> fi
bash: [: missing `]'
grep: ]: No such file or directory
```

Looks like the pipe `|` is causing problems here, since `[` can't find its last argument, and `grep` thinks its last argument is `]`. Since `[` (or the one we're using here anyway) is a shell builtin, we should be able to get some information about it using `help`

```
$ help [
[: [ arg... ]
    Evaluate conditional expression.

    This is a synonym for the "test" builtin, but the last argument must
    be a literal `]', to match the opening `['.
```

We can't use a pipe in the middle of a command's arguments. In other situations, we might be able to put the commands in a subshell by enclosing them in `(` `)`, but that is a syntax error in `[` (and `test`).

The real problem here is that what we are trying to pass to the `[` command is not something it can evaluate as true or false. If the argument you try to pass to `test` is a command, `test` does not use the exit status of that command as I think you are expecting. You can pass the *output* of a command to `[` using [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Substitution), but that is not what you or your code want(s) to do.

I think what your code is trying to do is check that `grep` found a `w` in the output of `namei -m somefile`. We don't need the `test` command for that at all.

```
$ help if
if: if COMMANDS; then COMMANDS; [ elif COMMANDS; then COMMANDS; ]... [ else COMMANDS; ] fi
    Execute commands based on conditional.

   The `if COMMANDS' list is executed.  If its exit status is zero, then the
   `then COMMANDS' list is executed.  Otherwise, each `elif COMMANDS' list is
   executed in turn, and if its exit status is zero, the corresponding
   `then COMMANDS' list is executed and the if command completes.  Otherwise,
   the `else COMMANDS' list is executed, if present.  The exit status of the
   entire construct is the exit status of the last command executed, or zero
   if no condition tested true.
```

So if we are only interested in whether a command succeeds, we can put the command as a condition for `if`:

```
$ if namei -m file | grep w; then echo "writeable"; fi
 -rw-rw-r-- file
writeable
```

You can even use `-q` to suppress output from `grep` and collect only its exit status (success if a match is found):

```
$ if namei -m file | grep  -q w; then echo "writeable"; fi
writeable
```

But that's not a good way to test whether the file is writeable by you. Let's try another test file:

```
$ touch file_with_w
$ chmod 444 file_with_w
$ stat -c %A file_with_w 
-r--r--r--
$ if namei -m file_with_w | grep  -q w; then echo "writeable"; fi
writeable
```

If we parse the output of `namei -m` for a file with a `w` in its name, this method will make it appear to be writeable even if it is read only for everyone.

Parsing the output of commands is sometimes the right way to get the information you want. But there is usually a better way, in the form of an option to that command, or a different command with a similar purpose.

Let's go back to `test` aka `[` command and see if it has any useful options. You can enter `help test`, or for more detail read [the Conditional Expressions section](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Conditional-Expressions) of the [Bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html)

```
File operators:
...
   -w FILE        True if the file is writable by you.
```

Aha! the `test` command has exactly what we want, as mentioned in answer to [Checking for a file and whether it is readable and writable](https://askubuntu.com/questions/558977/checking-for-a-file-and-whether-it-is-readable-and-writable)

```
$ if [ -w file ]; then echo "writeable"; fi
writeable
$ if [ -w file_with_w ]; then echo "writeable"; fi
$
```

That's right :)

But you mentioned that you wanted the command to output an error message if the file is not writeable, rather than a statement that it is writeable. For that we need an `else` statement

```
$ if [ -w file_with_w ]; then echo "writeable"; else echo "not writeable"; fi
not writeable
```

As a script, you could write that command like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ -w "$1" ]; then
   echo "writeable"
else
   echo "not writeable"
fi
```

Then you could give it execute permission (replace `script` with the actual filename)

```
chmod u+x script
```

and run it with the file you want to test as its argument (referenced in the script with `$1`):

```
$ ./script file
writeable
$ ./script file_with_w
not writeable
```

If you *only* want to get an error message when the file is non-writeable, and no output when it is, you can negate the test condition instead of writing an else:

```
$ if [ ! -w file_with_w ]; then echo "not writeable"; fi
not writeable
```

As Panther mentioned in [a comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/980658/command-to-check-whether-the-current-user-has-write-permission/980773#comment1576235_980658), you might also want to make use of the variable `$USER`, which should expand to the name of the user running the shell. You can thus make a more impressive error message:

```
$ if [ ! -w file_with_w ]; then echo "file is not writeable by $USER"; fi
file is not writeable by zanna
```

For simple `test` commands, you can also use `[` and `test` and `[[` without `if`, and use shell operators for the logic:

```
$ [ -w file_with_w ] || echo "not writeable"
not writeable
```

`||` is the shell's logical OR. It means *if the previous command failed, then execute the next command*

The shell's logical AND is `&&`:

```
$ [ ! -w file_with_w ] && echo "not writeable"
not writeable
```

`&&` means *if the previous command succeeded, then execute the next command*

All of this works because the `test` command gives a helpful exit status as described in `help test`:

```
Exit Status:
Returns success if EXPR evaluates to true; fails if EXPR evaluates to
false or an invalid argument is given.
```